# Using ASIHTTPRequest's Reachability

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest, reachability

I'm begin to use Reachability in my iOS project to test if there's internet connection or not.

My app consists in a `UITabBarController` with 3 different tabs. Each tab's root is a different `UIViewController`. In each controller I make several requests relying on user's actions.

My question is how to create a global function (or a macro) to use before **each** function that uses internet connection without rewriting this function in every controller.

Is possible to have a function that does this? I saw that there's a way to make the app sends notification relying on network status. But look at this example:

1. The user tap a `UIButton`
2. Network is available and the request starts.
3. If network goes down, how to stop the request and display for example a `UIAlertView`?

I've searched well but I can't find answers to my questions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reachability should not be used to detect if the network is available before making a network request because the act of making a network request can bring up the network if needed. Reachability should only be used to detect when the network becomes available after being unavailable.

Just try making the network request -- you'll get an error back if the network is unavailable. Usually the response will come back right away, but if the network is spotty it can take a while, so you shouldn't ever make synchronous network calls on the main thread. Use NSURLConnection if possible and you'll get callbacks when something happens.

Comment: I use `ASIHTTPRequest` for making asynchronous requests. Isn't there a more elegant way for checking if the network is available before making a request?

Comment: Not a reliable one, no. Make the request, check for errors. The device will power down the radios to conserve power and the act of making the request can power them up again.