# AFNetworking and No Internet Connection scenario

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I use `AFNetworking` in my app for every request (like login, get data from url, etc).

Take this for example: an user click on the login button and there's no connection, how to instantly display a `UIAlertView` that says the error? The **only** way is to wait the request timeout and execute the `failure` block? Isn't there a way that instantly check if there's connection or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As of 0.9, `AFHTTPClient` actually has network reachability built-in (a simpler interface to  Apple's aforementioned Reachability code). Just include the `SystemConfiguration` framework and use `-setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` to specify a response when the reachability state changes.

Comment: Hi mattt and thanks for you reply. But your suggestion is to check for current status of internet connection before **every** method that uses internet and if there's no connection displays an alert?

Comment: No, not at all. `AFHTTPClient` monitors for reachability changes and executes the specified block when that happens. The block has a single argument, which is a boolean for whether or not the `baseURL` is reachable.

Comment: I've subclassed `AFHTTPClient` and I've overridden `-setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` with an `NSLog(@"test")` inside but the statement is never executed. Why?

Comment: @FredCollins Check that you've included the SystemConfiguration framework. If that's not linked to the project, that code won't run.

Comment: @mattt could you add some sample code so I could see what should I do. Thanks

Comment: @FredCollins You don't override the method, you call it on your subclass and pass in a block which contains the code you want to run. Make sure you take out  your override or it WILL NOT WORK.

Comment: Add `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` to the header prefix of the project (Prefix.pch). This is required step after adding SystemConfiguration framework.

Comment: @mattt I have set `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` before setting up a `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure`, is this the right way to do it? if that's the case, when I get a status of `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable`, how do I cancel the operation, or would the failure block be automatically called when it sees a `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable`?

Answer (score 28):

With `AFNetworking` these are the steps that one has to follow in order to take advantage of `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` after adding the AFNetworing classes -

1. Add `SystemConfiguration.framework` to your project
2. In pch file add `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>`
3. Assuming that you have a subclass of `AFHTTPClient` in this subclass add below lines of code in init function -

```
[self setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"changed %d", status);
        //your code here
    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use "Reachability" to determine if the device is connected to the network.
Here is the link to the Apple Doc. : [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

For example :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNetworkChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {
  //Your UIAlertView
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the **`AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification`**.
Every time a http request will fail, the alert pops up and informs the user

```
- (void)addNetworkObserver
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(HTTPOperationDidFinish:) 
                                                name:AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification 
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)HTTPOperationDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
   AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)[notification object];
   if (![operation isKindOfClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]]) {
       return;
   }
   if (operation.error) {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection error"
                                                       message:@"Missing connection to the internet"
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

       [alert show];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Reachability?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4772173/189804)

You can check whether you have a plausible reason for trying a connection before you do it.

Looks like the [Apple Sample Project for Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4) shows how to get an initial status.

Comment: For any case where reachability returns no, won't any socket i/o fail immediately, too?

Comment: Yes, that's how Reachability works but it gives you extras like the ability to receive notifications when reachability changes - interrupts, not polling.

Comment: Excuse me Adam, but if the network is not used but the device is connected and I check for network status, Reachability tell me I've no connection. This answer explain what I would say in a better way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9186073/719127

Comment: Right. I guess my point was for the question at hand, using reachability isn't any better than just trying to make the connection.

Comment: Updated with a link to the code sample - checking reachability before making your actual request can be done.

Comment: Thanks guy, I'll try to implement it in while and I come back with the response. :-)