# IOS - best way to queue requests to be sent when connection is reestablished

Tags: ios, httpwebrequest, restkit

in my IOS application I have an in-app purchase in my app and I need to send receipt to my web service to assign premium content to a user account. I need this to be reliable even when the connection is lost right after the in-app purchase completes.

Are there any solid libraries out there that can take a request and execute it when connection is reestablished?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), a very well-made networking library which wraps NSURLConnection.

In order to use it for your purpose you need to take advantage of the reachability build-in  features of `AFHTTPClient` as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9255830/846273).

Basically you can execute and arbitrary block whenever the reachability status of the network changes using the `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` method of `AFHTTPClient`.

Just remember to link and import the `SystemConfiguration` framework, otherwise it won't work.