# Timed Out while using AFHTTPSessionOperation

Tags: afnetworking

Can anybody tell me why my call "timed out"? My app just hangs there, the success:^(NSURLSessionTask* operation, id response) section of the folowing code was never executed.

```
return [self beginRequestController:@"myController" action:@"myAction" parameters:parameters 
success:^(NSURLSessionTask* operation, id response)
{
    NSLog(@"This is NOT being called --->>>: %@",  response);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask* operation, NSError* error)
{
    //Handle the error
}];

- (NSOperation*) beginRequestController:(NSString*)controller action: (NSString*)action parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters success: (RequestSuccess)success failure:(RequestFailure)failure
{
NSOperation *operation = [AFHTTPSessionOperation operationWithManager:manager HTTPMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:parameters uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress: nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Reponse --->>>: %@", responseObject );
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error --->>>: %@", error);
    }];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
return operation;
}
```

Comment: There is only one operation. I did try limit the maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 and it did not fix my problem. There is no error message. I really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Thank you @Rob, it is not hitting the success block from the first call, there is no failure and actually it executed the success block from the second call, but after that, it just freezing indefinitely and eventually timed out. What confused me is why it didn't return back to the first success block after the second call is completed successfully? It didn't execute the failure block from the first call either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing blocks to `beginRequestController`, but that method doesn't do anything with them. You want to call those blocks. E.g.

```
- (NSOperation *)beginRequestController:(NSString *)controller action:(NSString *)action parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(RequestSuccess)success failure:(RequestFailure)failure {
    NSOperation *operation = [AFHTTPSessionOperation operationWithManager:manager HTTPMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:parameters uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response --->>>: %@", responseObject);
        if (success)
            success(task, responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error --->>>: %@", error);
        if (failure) 
            failure(task, error);
    }];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    return operation;
}
```

Or, even simpler:

```
- (NSOperation *)beginRequestController:(NSString *)controller action:(NSString *)action parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(RequestSuccess)success failure:(RequestFailure)failure {
    NSOperation *operation = [AFHTTPSessionOperation operationWithManager:manager HTTPMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:parameters uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress: nil success:success failure:failure];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    return operation;
}
```

Comment: you are super awesome! That fixed it!