# How to set ticket with AFHTTPSessionOperation or AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: afnetworking-3

Does anyone know how to set ticket inside AFHTTPSessionOperation?
This is the previous call using AFNetworking framework 1.0

```
NSURLRequest* request = [self.myClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", controller, action] parameters:parameters];
AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [self.myClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
[self.mirrorClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

The ticket is stored inside the self.myClient. self.myClient.ticket

But I'm not sure how to implement that in the following call using AFHTTPSessionOperation with AFNetworking framework 3.1.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
AFHTTPRequestSerializer <AFURLRequestSerialization> * requestSerializer = manager.requestSerializer;
[requestSerializer  setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.myClient.ticket] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSOperation *operation = [AFHTTPSessionOperation operationWithManager:manager HTTPMethod:@"POST" 
URLString:urlString parameters:parameters 
uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress: nil 
success:success failure:failure];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks basically correct. You could simplify the `requestSerializer` configuration a tad, and I might not instantiate a new session for every request, but the following worked fine for me:

```
- (void)performRequest:(NSString *)urlString
            parameters:(id)parameters
               success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
               failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure {

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:self.myClient.ticket forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSOperation *operation = [AFHTTPSessionOperation operationWithManager:manager
                                                               HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                URLString:urlString
                                                               parameters:parameters
                                                           uploadProgress:nil
                                                         downloadProgress:nil
                                                                  success:success
                                                                  failure:failure];
    [self.queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

I watched it in [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com), and the ticket, `12345678` appeared in my request header, as expected:

[image]

I suspect your problem rests elsewhere. This code does set the `Authorization` header to `ticket`. Make sure this is the right place to set the `ticket`. Also, make sure the `ticket` is what you think it is.

Comment: you are right!  The problem came from my ticket, it doesn't have the right data.