# Some requests time out with no clear reason

Tags: ios, rest, afnetworking, nsurlrequest, connection-timeout

I encountered a bug I can't understand and for now it happens only on a specific device. It happens on an iPhone 5 with iOS 6 but unfortunately I don't have access to another one to check if it's related to the fact that it's an iPhone 5.

The problem is that some specific network requests made to our server API time out although the connection is fast and there seems to be no server-side problem as the server acts normally responding to the same request from other devices.

I use `AFNetworking` to make my http requests.

I have subclassed `AFHTTPClient` and for that specific request I use it like this

```
[[MyClient sharedInstance] putPath:@"myPath"
                        parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"y" forKey:@"set"]
                           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
                                     // do something with response
                           }
                           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                     // tell user there an error occurred
                           }];
```

I would appreciate if someone points me to some possible reasons this is happening or things to analyze to understand what is happening.

Comment: Does this work on your simulator?

Comment: @DannyLin Yes it does! It also works with all the other devices on which I tried (I haven't tried on another iPhone 5)

Answer (score 2):

There is a near-zero chance that the issue relates to the interaction between AFNetworking and a specific device - it's likely one or the other.

### Testing AFNetworking

AFNetworking does provide build-in detection of connectivity changes.  Set a block using `AFHTTPClient`'s `-setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` method.  This will let you know when an Internet connection is lost, and will allow you to adjust your app's behavior as needed.

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612051/1445366) provides sample code and setup instructions.

Here are the values for the `status` variable, for your reference:

```
AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown          = -1,
AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable     = 0,
AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN = 1,
AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi = 2,
```

### Testing the Device

Here are something you can try to isolate the issue to your device:

• Download [Fing](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107) and compare network performance on different devices

• Do a data speed test on [testmyiphone.com](http://testmyiphone.com/)

• Check the device's [parental controls](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213) to see if anything would conflict with your app's behavior

• Restore the device, without restoring from backup, in iTunes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by monitoring the actual HTTP request/responses that you are sending by using a tool such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

You can use Charles as a proxy for your actual device, check out the instructions [here](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! How is using this tool different than debugging on Xcode and inspect the requests and responses?

Comment: @Moxy Charles (and Wireshark, a similar tool) can give you specific info about send/receive times.  Network timing issues are tricky to solve in the debugger because pausing the app ("breaking") can affect whether the issue you're testing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check your iphone wifi network. This happen to me in the past when i am connected to my company's corporate network and i tried to connect to my server and there is a request timeout. This may be due to some proxy issues.

Firstly is your server intranet? If it is not, try using 3G to connect to the server instead.

If it is intranet try to find an alternative company network or use VPN if your company has one

Comment: We are using a 3G connection and it works well for other requests.